# Firebase Crashlytics console doesn`t show data flowing from Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

Does somebody integration of Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase. Because, I bound Fabric Crashlytics with the app from Firebase, then I`s going to Firebase Crashlytics and there is no information about crashes, unlike in Fabric Crashlytics(there is all information about crashes and non-fatals exceptions. There is only the message from Firebase about unavailable information from crashlytics of Fabric. Please help.[image] Message is in russian, but here is translation: "For now information about existing projects of Fabric is unavailable on panel of Crashlytics. You can see it on the panel of Fabric"

Comment: Did you check firebase crash reporting in console??? It takes some time to pull all the crash analytics from fabric into firebase crash reporting.

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn`t pull any information to Firebase Crash Reporting. There is only the advertisment of Fabric Crashlytic @MohammedFarhan

Comment: If you're already using Fabric Crashlytics, we recommend to keep using it via the Fabric dashboard for now and we'll have a migration path to Firebase Crashlytics in the coming months.

Comment: Thank yout for the advice. I think that all the problems around this topic exist because of Firebase Crashlytics are in beta now @Alexizamerican

Comment: @Alexizamerican Fabric Mobile apps will go off after 30 November 2018, what is best way to migrate